# Stata twoway graph of means with confidence intervals

Tags: graph, stata

Using

```
clear 
score      group     test
 2          0         A
 3          0         B
 6          0         B
 8          0         A
 2          0         A
 2          0         A
 10         1         B
 7          1         B
 8          1         A
 5          1         A
 10         1         A
 11         1         B
end
```

I want to scatter plot mean `score` by `group` for each `test` (same graph) with confidence intervals (the real data has thousands of observations). The resulting graph would have two sets of two dots. One set of dots for `test==a` (`group==0` vs `group==1`) and one set of dots for `test==b` (`group==0` vs `group==1`).

My current approach works but it is laborious. I compute all of the needed statistics using `egen`: the mean, number of observations, standard deviations...for each group by test. I then `collapse` the data and plot.

There has to be another way, no?

I *assumed* that Stata would be able to take as its input the `score` `group` and `test` variables and then compute and present this pretty standard graph.

After spending a lot of time on Google, I had to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there are user-written programs, I lean towards `statsby` as a basic approach here. Discussion is accessible [in this paper](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=gr0045).

This example takes your data example (almost executable code). Some choices depend on the large confidence intervals implied. Note that if your version of Stata is not up-to-date, the syntax of `ci` will be different. (Just omit `means`.)

```
clear 
input score      group    str1 test
 2          0         A
 3          0         B
 6          0         B
 8          0         A
 2          0         A
 2          0         A
 10         1         B
 7          1         B
 8          1         A
 5          1         A
 10         1         A
 11         1         B
end
save cj12 , replace 

* test A 
statsby mean=r(mean) ub=r(ub) lb=r(lb) N=r(N), by(group) clear : ///
ci means score if test == "A"  
gen test = "A" 
save cj12results, replace 

* test B 
use cj12 
statsby mean=r(mean) ub=r(ub) lb=r(lb) N=r(N), by(group) clear : ///
ci means score if test == "B"  
gen test = "B" 
append using cj12results 

* graph; show sample sizes too, but where to show them is empirical 
set scheme s1color 
gen where = -20 
scatter mean group, ms(O) mcolor(blue) || ///
rcap ub lb group, lcolor(blue) ///
by(test, note("95% confidence intervals") legend(off))  ///
subtitle(, fcolor(ltblue*0.2)) ///
ytitle(score) xla(0 1) xsc(r(-0.25 1.25)) yla(-10(10)10, ang(h)) || ///
scatter where group, ms(none) mla(N) mlabpos(12) mlabsize(*1.5)
```

[image]

We can't compare your complete code or your graph, because you show neither.

Comment: This does save a few lines of code but I was hoping it would be even less manual than that and creating a new dataset is not ideal. Can you list the user written programs you know of, off hand? No need to explain them, I can do the research.

Comment: Stata is programmable and this is a forum for professional and enthusiast programmers, so why not write your own program to do what you want? The essence is that writing code to graph confidence intervals implies specifying (a) what confidence intervals you want (b) for what data (c) plotted how. (a) (b) (c) together is large and complicated territory. A program to do all that in generality would be fiendishly complicated and I don't think it exists. But for example, `ciplot` (SSC) does at least some of what you want, but it is not very general and I am not maintaining or extending it.